# Who had called my Java Application?

Tags: java, jar

Let's say I have a Java application bundled as jar (`TestExec.jar`).

The problem occurs when I want to trace about who had called my application, i mean being stand-alone application some body had called through **command line** (as if `java -jar TextExec.jar`) or just **double click** or may be through **scheduled tasks (as in windows)**.

So i wanna...trace that..whether it is through **command line or double click or scheduled taks**.

Is there any facility or something like that  :)

Comment: Why is that weired requirement?

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez....you don't have to swear...i know you didn't....ha ha ha ha....@Azodious....say crazy requirement is more appropriate than weired....ha ha ha....but the question remains same...  :)

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez....thanks...ha ha ha..

Comment: Why...so many...punctuation...marks?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to tell is based on the command line arguments or the environment. You may be able to work this out indirectly but I suggest adding a specific argument which tells your program how it is expected to behave.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your jar has a main class and you want to track who used the jar by invoking it, you can get the user information in one of the following ways:

- using `user.name` from the environment (very less secure)
- get the details of the user from the underlying OS (using NTSystem/UnixSystem)
- authenticate the user using a directory server like Active Directory or Kerberos KDC.

Once you get the details of the user, you can log them at some common place.

Comment: @Vikdor...that's correct...and i really appreciate your effort..but can we trace how that had bean called...i mean command line or double click or scheduled task....!!!!

Comment: I don;t think he wanted to know the user - he wanted to know the source from which it was called

Answer (score 0):

You can create external files that call it with different parameter values. for example create a batch file that passes src=bat while another file that creates a windows service and will call it with src=service.
Without passing something yourself I don't think you can tell.

Comment: @arikg...if the call is through scheduled tasks...then windows service will be a bad idea.....and secondly i must have three different jar file i mean one for command-line...one for service and another for bat file....is it so??

Comment: You don't need to have 3 different jars you just need 3 different calling ways with different environment properties.
lets say you create a batch file that calls your jar but adds an extra env parameter -Dcaller.src=bat and then you create another  one for the scheduled taks and it passes -Dcaller.src=sched and then there's also the double click which passes nothing. now you can get the System.getProperty("caller.src") and know where it was called from.

Now the question is how you make people call the right fle from command line and right file for scheduled task